#citus Coordinator node setup and worker node setup are not working
I would like to setup citus and use it. But the error occurs like below.
Please take a look at my progress and let me know if I missed anything.


Please refer to the table below for server configuration.



division
host IP




Coordinator
192.168.54.176


Worker_node1
192.168.54.117


Worker_node2
192.168.54.118






info
version




OS
CentOS7.9


PostgreSQL
15.6



postgres=# \dx 
                        installed extension list<br>

      name      |  version  |   schema   |             description <br>
----------------+--------+------------+------------------------------ <br>
 citus          | 11.3-2 | pg_catalog | Citus distributed database <br>
 citus_columnar | 11.3-1 | pg_catalog | Citus Columnar extension <br>
 plpgsql        | 1.0    | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language <br>
(3rows)

Before start, listen_adrresses ='*' in postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf settings are like below.
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust


postgres=# SELECT citus_set_coordinator_host('192.168.54.176', 5432);
 citus_set_coordinator_host
----------------------------

(1row)


nothing has changed...
postgres=# SELECT * from citus_add_node('192.168.54.117', 5432);
ERROR:  Node cannot add itself as a worker.
HINT:  Add the node as a coordinator by using: SELECT citus_set_coordinator_host('192.168.54.117', 5432);
postgres=# SELECT * from citus_add_node('192.168.54.118', 5432);
ERROR:  Node cannot add itself as a worker.
HINT:  Add the node as a coordinator by using: SELECT citus_set_coordinator_host('192.168.54.118', 5432);


I ran it reffering to the official citus page linked below.
https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.2/installation/multi_node_rhel.html#steps-to-be-executed-on-all-nodes
I want to setup citus correctly.
